# Count the number of words and lines that have multiple vowels

Tags: python, performance, strings, array

I am working on this coding problem:

> Count the number of words & lines that have more than X vowels for every Y words in every Z line.

Basically the input string has multiple lines and I need to count words that have X or more vowels in them. But the constraint is I need to consider only every *Z*th line as well as only every *Y*th word in those lines.

For example let's say I need to count every 3rd word that has 2 or more vowels in every 3rd line. So here X=2, Y=3, Z=3.

Input string:

```
"1.When I first brought my cat home.
 2.It cost a lot to adopt her.
 3.I paid forty dollars for it.
 4.And then I had to buy litter, a litterbox.
 5.Also bought food, and dishes for her to eat out of. 
 6.There's a **leash** law for cats in Fort **Collins**.
 7.If they're not in your yard they have to be on a leash. 
 8.Anyway, my cat is my best friend. 
 9.I'm glad I got her. 
 10.She sleeps under the covers with me when it's cold."
```

Output should be:

```
Word Count: 2, Line Count: 1
```

So based on criteria of Z=3, i.e. "count every 3rd line", the lines to be considered are lines 3, 6, 9.

In these lines we need to count Y=3, i.e. every 3rd word. So the words to be considered are *forty*, *it* from line 3, *leash*, *cats*, *Collins* from line 6, and *I* from line 9.

Given these criteria, the matching words with 2 or more vowels are found only in line 6 with words *leash* and *Collins*, so the output is `WordCount = 2` and `LineCount = 1`.

```py
class StringCount:  

  lines = list();
  totalMatchedLines = 0;
  totalMatchedWords = 0;
  matchedChars = 0;

  def __init__(self, inputString, vowelCount, skipWords, skipLines, wordDelimiter, lineDelimiter):
    self.inputString = inputString;
    self.vowelCount = vowelCount;
    self.skipWords = skipWords;
    self.skipLines = skipLines;
    self.wordDelimiter = wordDelimiter;

  def splitLines(self):
    if self.inputString.strip() == "":
      print ("Please enter a valid string!");
      return False;      
    self.lines = self.inputString.splitlines();

  def splitWords(self):      
    self.matchedWords = 0;
    self.matchedLines = 0;
    self.linesLength = len(self.lines);

    if self.linesLength < self.skipLines:
      print ("Input string should be greater than {0}" .format(self.skipLines));
      return False;

    lineCount = self.skipLines - 1;
    wordCount = self.skipWords - 1;
    lineInUse = "";
    words = list();

    while (lineCount < self.linesLength):
      self.matchedWords = 0;
      self.matchedLines = 0;
      self.words = self.lines[lineCount].split();
      self.wordsLength = len(self.words);
      wordCount = self.skipWords - 1;

      while (wordCount < self.wordsLength):
        self.matchedChars = 0;       
        for i in self.words[wordCount].lower():
          if(i=='a' or i=='e' or i=='i' or i=='o' or i=='u'):
            self.matchedChars += 1;              
        if self.matchedChars >= self.vowelCount:
          self.matchedWords += 1;
        wordCount += self.skipWords;

      if self.matchedWords > 0:
        self.matchedLines += 1;

      self.totalMatchedWords += self.matchedWords;
      self.totalMatchedLines += self.matchedLines;
      lineCount += self.skipLines;

    print ("WordCount = %s" % (self.totalMatchedWords));
    print ("LineCount = %s" % (self.totalMatchedLines));
```

Code to invoke the class:

```py
mystring = "1.When I first brought my cat home.
 2.It cost a lot to adopt her.
 3.I paid forty dollars for it.
 4.And then I had to buy litter, a litterbox.
 5.Also bought food, and dishes for her to eat out of. 
 6.There's a **leash** law for cats in Fort **Collins**.
 7.If they're not in your yard they have to be on a leash. 
 8.Anyway, my cat is my best friend. 
 9.I'm glad I got her. 
 10.She sleeps under the covers with me when it's cold.";

myobjectx = StringCount(myString, 2, 3, 3, " ", "\n");
myobjectx.splitLines();
myobjectx.splitWords();
```

Since this is my first piece of Python code, I wanted to check how to optimize this code in both performance and line optimization. Is there any inbuilt functionality to shorten the multiple `while` loops and the `for` loop?

Comment: `optimize this code in both performance and line optimization` readability (→maintainability) first!

Comment: @200_success, just updated the post with invocation code.

Comment: For the record, `mystring` spans multiple lines, and needs to be triple-quoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Style

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is the official style guide for Python.  Unless you have a good reason to deviate, you should use `lower_case_with_underscores` for variable names and method names.  Terminating statements with semicolons is a faux pas in Python.  Also, indentation should be four spaces, which is a particularly important convention to follow in Python since whitespace is significant.

## Interface and Behavior

The `wordDelimiter` and `lineDelimiter` parameters are completely ignored.

It's not obvious that the proper way to invoke this code is to call `.splitLines()` followed by `.splitWords()`.  It's even more surprising that `.splitWords()` prints anything at all — from the name of the method, I wouldn't have guessed that it would have that effect.  In contrast, my solution below makes it more obvious what the program does:

```
wc, lc = StringCounter(2, 3, 3).word_and_line_counts(fileinput.input())
print("Word count = {0}".format(wc))
print("Line count = {0}".format(lc))
```

In my opinion, an input that is an empty string or that has an insufficient number of lines should not be an error.  After all, a line that contains too few words isn't an error, right?

Consider accepting the input as a line iterator, rather than as a string.  Python will naturally give you a line iterator if you read from a file or from `sys.stdin`.

### Eloquent looping and filtering

In my solution below, I have defined three [lambda expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) to help with the iterating and counting.  Defining these three short functions helps make the code's purpose more obvious.

A lot of loops in Python can be written very expressively using the `itertools` module.  In particular, [`itertools.islice(iterable, start, stop, step)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) will skip to every *n*<sup>th</sup> element.

Counting can be done using the [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) built-in function with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions).  Furthermore, you can take advantage of the fact that `True` and `False` are treated as `1` and `0`, respectively, when adding.  My `line_count += (matched_words > 0)` is equivalent to your

> ```
> if self.matchedWords > 0:
>   self.matchedLines += 1;
> ```

My `sum((c in 'aeiouAEIOU') for c in word) >= x` is equivalent to your

> ```
> for i in self.words[wordCount].lower():
>   if(i=='a' or i=='e' or i=='i' or i=='o' or i=='u'):
>     self.matchedChars += 1;              
> if self.matchedChars >= self.vowelCount:
>   self.matchedWords += 1;
> ```

### Suggested solution

```
from itertools import islice

class StringCounter:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        # Function that takes lines and yields every zth line
        self.candidate_lines = lambda lines: islice(lines, z - 1, None, z)

        # Function that takes one line and yields every yth word in it
        self.candidate_words = lambda line: islice(line.split(), y - 1, None, y)

        # Function that takes words and counts how many of them have >= x vowels
        self.vowel_rich_words = lambda words: sum(
             sum((c in 'aeiouAEIOU') for c in word) >= x
             for word in words
        )

    def word_and_line_counts(self, line_iter):
        word_count = line_count = 0
        for line in self.candidate_lines(line_iter):
            matched_words = self.vowel_rich_words(self.candidate_words(line))
            word_count += matched_words
            line_count += (matched_words > 0)
        return word_count, line_count

mystring = """1.When I first brought my cat home.
 2.It cost a lot to adopt her.
 3.I paid forty dollars for it.
 4.And then I had to buy litter, a litterbox.
 5.Also bought food, and dishes for her to eat out of. 
 6.There's a **leash** law for cats in Fort **Collins**.
 7.If they're not in your yard they have to be on a leash. 
 8.Anyway, my cat is my best friend. 
 9.I'm glad I got her. 
 10.She sleeps under the covers with me when it's cold."""

wc, lc = StringCounter(2, 3, 3).word_and_line_counts(mystring.splitlines())
print("Word count = {0}".format(wc))
print("Line count = {0}".format(lc))
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I have never used python before so wrote this basic solution as per basic functions I learned in tutorials. But this is nicely explained. Thanks again.